# Assign class using javascript only if there is something in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to assign class by using javascript when there is some values in input field (text field)

-- detailed --

Actually im using background watermark in the input field. So when someone click & type it on the input field then i will clear the background watermark image by css (using :focus selector).

In that way if he move to the next field then still the background watermark showing with the typed text (because onfocus is lift to the next field).

Anyone please?

If so i will make style to clear background watermark image using the class!

Answer (score 3):

```
if($.trim($('input[type=text]').val()).length) {
  $(some_target).addClass('new_class');
}
```

[.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/trim)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val)

Complete code should look like following:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function() {
  var targetInput = this; // keeping reference of input
  if($.trim(this.value).length) {
    // code for remove watermark
    $(targetInput).addClass('class_for_watermark');
  } else {
    // code for add watermark
    $(targetInput).removeClass('class_for_watermark');
  }
});
```

And you don't need to `:focus` css.

Comment: +1, there is also `.toggleClass` which could simplify the `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
if ( $input.val() ) {
  // Has a value, do something
  $element.addClass('myClass');
}
```

Comment: Resolving the boolean state of an input's value could return false if the input is 0 or a string containing "0", "false", "null" or any other javascript value that is equal to false.